# how to send the selected id into another layout in android

Tags: android, json, node.js

I have spinner which contain multiple elements, once i click on a specific item it should send to another layout which contains a list of element based on the id chosen but i don't know how to do it.

here is my main class which has a spinner

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String folder = spinner.getItemAtPosition( spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),folder,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BuildingsListActivity.class);
                // Sending value to another activity using intent.
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FOLDER_NAME, folder);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
    }
   // spinner function
    private void loadSpinnerFolders (String url) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String dossier = jsonObject1.getString("nom");
                            Folders.add(dossier);
                        }

                    // spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Folders));

                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                            (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Folders);
                        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is your question that you are unable to find out which item was selected in spinner?

Comment: yes i want to get the id of the folder chosen

Comment: I believe there is still some confusion. Suppose you have 4 items in your spinner and 3rd item is selected, is the id you are talking about value 3 in this case. Or is it some different id.

Comment: yes i want the id 3 which i will send in put.extra in order to get some other data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unaware of your models and structure. So i am giving a related code -

**Folder Model**

```
public class Folder {

    int id;
    String spinnerItem;

    Folder() {
    }

    public Folder(int id, String spinnerItem) {
        this.id = id;
        this.spinnerItem = spinnerItem;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSpinnerItem() {
        return spinnerItem;
    }

    public void setSpinnerItem(String spinnerItem) {
        this.spinnerItem = spinnerItem;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return spinnerItem;
    }
}
```

**MainClass**

```
public class MainClass extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = findViewById(R.id.s);
        Folder folder = new Folder();

        final ArrayAdapter<Folder> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Folder>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        folder.setId(4);
        folder.setSpinnerItem("Jelly Bean");
        adapter.add(folder);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent in = new Intent(this, NextAct.class);
                in.putExtra("ItemId", adapter.getItem(i).getId());
                startActivity(in);

                // This will retrieve id of selected Spinner Item (id - the one in Folder model) i.e. when Jelly Bean is selected, 4 will be passed in NextAct.
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not really working since i have to get the id of the folder chosen from the spinner and not define it

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have 4 folders for your spinner

folder0->0th Position in your spinner (First item of spinner, position starts from 0)

folder1->1st Position in your spinner
.....
In this method

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView,View selectedItemView, int position, long id)
position is the position of selected item

Now in your code

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                int position=spinner.getSelectedItemPosition(); //or i 
                String folder = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),folder,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BuildingsListActivity.class);
                // Sending value to another activity using intent.

                //folder is the selected item
                //position is the corresponding position of selected value in the spinner
                intent.putExtra(ID_KEY_NAME, String.valueOf(position+1));
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FOLDER_NAME, folder);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
```

Alternatively, you can also use spinner.getSelectedItemPosition(); to get the position.

Read more about [Spinners here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner)